# IFrame default size in FF

Tags: javascript, iframe, size, default

I need the exact borders of the iframe element relative to the whole page. Since I can only get one point (topleft) of the element, I also need the size (width and height) - which aren't always set.

**In case** the size isn't set I need to find a way to get the default size.  I prefer a solution in pure JS without JQuery.

Finding the default size with a debugger can help, but I wanted to know if there's a different way that will give me a general and not "hard-coded" solution (i.e some kind of "getDefaultIframeSize").

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always just put the iframe on your page without any width/height details, load the page and then inspect the iframe element with something like FireBug

http://getfirebug.com/

Firebug will tell you the computed width and height of the window

Comment: Then why not just set the frame size yourself?

Comment: @eve:  He's not giving you a final solution that requires extra software.  He's giving you a method that you can use to answer your original question yourself.

Comment: @eve: Ah if you want a javascript solution you can just use JQuery to get the height and width of the iFrame http://api.jquery.com/height/ for example

Comment: @CraigW: jQuery is how I'd do it too.  But eve clearly stated, _"I prefer not using extra software."_  Sometimes these questions would be easier to answer if the OP just took the time to write it all out with more detail up front.

Comment: @eve:  It's all very vague.  The "default" size is the default size... it would not change.   Once you get the default size, then you'll always have it.

Comment: From what it sounds like, a parent element width/height would be more useful than a "default CSS width/height per browser". I think the OP is potentially wanting something that is not what the question captures.